# IF(<variable>) definition

Tags: cmake, bazel

I am trying to understand what this code means in the [following cmake file](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-extensions/blob/5489325df9f07af5f39cce101a91cee7fad2eb62/cmake/ext_ortlib.cmake#L4):

```
if(_ONNXRUNTIME_EMBEDDED)
  set(ONNXRUNTIME_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/onnxruntime/core/session)
  set(ONNXRUNTIME_LIB_DIR "")
elseif(ONNXRUNTIME_PKG_DIR)
  set(ONNXRUNTIME_INCLUDE_DIR ${ONNXRUNTIME_PKG_DIR}/include)
  set(ONNXRUNTIME_LIB_DIR ${ONNXRUNTIME_PKG_DIR}/lib)
elseif(OCOS_ONNXRUNTIME_PKG_URI)
```

I initially thought it may mean if the variable like `ONNXRUNTIME_PKG_DIR` is defined, but I'm confused as to the difference between this as something like

```
if(DEFINED ONNXRUNTIME_PKG_DIR)
```

I ask because it seems like specifying these entries should override the corresponding variables [here](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-extensions/blob/5489325df9f07af5f39cce101a91cee7fad2eb62/CMakeLists.txt#L79-L82). I have a simple Bazel cmake build to do this, but specifying `OCOS_ONNXRUNTIME_PKG_URI` doesn't seem to do anything:

```
cmake(
    name = "onnx_extensions",
    lib_source = ":all_srcs",
    cache_entries = {
        "OCOS_ONNXRUNTIME_PKG_URI": "./onnxruntime-win-x64-1.16.0.zip",
        "OCOS_ONNXRUNTIME_VERSION": "1.16.2",
    },
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "@onnx_runtime//:onnx_runtime"
    ]
)
```

Comment: The command `if(_ONNXRUNTIME_EMBEDDED)` checks whether the variable `_ONNXRUNTIME_EMBEDDED` exists and has non-false value. This can be easily found in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#basic-expressions).